# Strange performance issue with AMD's ACML BLAS/LAPACK library

Tags: c, performance, linear-algebra, lapack, blas

I asked this question over at the AMD developers forum a few days ago, but haven't gotten an answer.  Maybe someone here has some insight.
http://devgurus.amd.com/thread/167492

I am running ACML version 5.3.1, libacml_mp with gfortran_fma4 on Opteron 6348 processors on Ubuntu 12.04.

What happens is the performance of a call to dsyev (eigen decomposition) slows down dramatically (by a factor of 10+) if I first make a call to dpotrf (cholesky decomposition).  It makes no sense at all to me why this would happen.  Maybe there is some kind of cache I need to clear or something like that.

Here is a simple C program that reproduces the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <acml.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
  double * x = malloc(1000000 * sizeof(double));
  double * y = malloc(1000000 * sizeof(double));
  double * eig0 = malloc(1000000 * sizeof(double));
  double * eig1 = malloc(1000000 * sizeof(double));
  double * eigw = malloc(1000 * sizeof(double));
  double * chol = malloc(1000000 * sizeof(double));

  clock_t t0,t1;
  int info;
  int i;

  // generate a random matrix
  for(i = 0; i<1000000; ++i){
    x[i] = rand() / (double) RAND_MAX;
  }

  // compute y = xx^T so that y is symmetric positive definite
  dgemm('N','T',1000,1000,1000,1,x,1000,x,1000,0,y,1000);

  // make a copy of y for cholesky and eigen decompositions
  for(i = 0; i<1000000; ++i){
    chol[i] = y[i];
    eig0[i] = y[i];
    eig1[i] = y[i];
  }

  // first eigenvalue test
  t0 = clock();
  dsyev('V','U',1000,eig0,1000,eigw,&info);
  t1 = clock();
  printf("Eigen decomposition time: %d\n", (t1-t0)/1000);

  // cholesky
  dpotrf('U',1000,chol,1000,&info);

  // second eigenvalue test, after cholesky
  t0 = clock();
  dsyev('V','U',1000,eig1,1000,eigw,&info);
  t1 = clock();
  printf("Eigen decomposition time: %d\n", (t1-t0)/1000);
}
```

Here is the output:

```
Eigen decomposition time: 8120
Eigen decomposition time: 95140
```

If I comment out the dpotrf line, then it works fine:

```
Eigen decomposition time: 8150
Eigen decomposition time: 8210
```